# How to get matching elements from array and change array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

if array has matching ids change object to one object without effecting original array with below code it returns only matching objects but i want expected result as mentioned

main.ts

```
const arr = [{
            "body": {
                "specialtyID": "7114798",
                "sourceSystem": "HBS",
                "rxInfos": [{
                    "drugNdc": "00445450085",
                    "rxNumber": "14678904"
                }]

            },
            {
                "body": {
                    "specialtyID": "7114798",
                    "sourceSystem": "HBS",
                    "rxInfos": [{
                        "drugNdc": "00004080085",
                        "rxNumber": "1459004"
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "body": {
                    "specialtyID": "7908398",
                    "sourceSystem": "HBS",
                    "rxInfos": [{
                        "drugNdc": "06789955085",
                        "rxNumber": "1478604"
                    }]
                }
            }

        ]


        const tempArray = arr;

        function arrayMatch(temp, arr) {
            const finalArray = [];
            arr.forEach((element) => {
                    tempArray.forEach((temp) => {
                            if (temp.speicaltyID === element.specialtyID) {
                                temp.rxInfos.forEach((rxInfo) => {
                                    element.rxInfos.push(rxInfo);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        finalArray = arr;

                    });
                return finalArray

            }
```

expected output

```
 const arr = [{
                        "body": {
                            "specialtyID": "7114798",
                            "sourceSystem": "HBS",
                            "rxInfos": [{
                                    "drugNdc": "00445450085",
                                    "rxNumber": "14678904"
                                },
                                {
                                    "drugNdc": "00004080085",
                                    "rxNumber": "1459004"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "body": {
                                "specialtyID": "7908398",
                                "sourceSystem": "HBS",
                                "rxInfos": [{
                                    "drugNdc": "06789955085",
                                    "rxNumber": "1478604"
                                }]
                            }
                        }

                    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Zze function is returning array only for matching objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method to achieve your desired result:

```
const result = arr.reduce((container, value) => {
    const compare     = ({ body }) => body.specialtyID === value.body.specialtyID;
    const isExists    = container.some(compare);
    const pushRxInfos = container.map(item => compare(item) ? item.body.rxInfos.push(...value.body.rxInfos) : item);

    isExists ? pushRxInfos : container.push(value);

    return container;
}, []);
```

Comment: yes that is the solution i was looking only issue is matching element is being created under another nested array , How it can be pushed to same level where rxInfos elements are in object

Comment: it is coming like `[{
        element1
    },

    [{

        matched element
    }]
]` matched element should not wrap in array

Comment: @hussain had updated my answer. Just need to use the spread operator to get the raw data from the array  -   .push(...value.body.rxInfos) and it will now be [{ element1 }, { matched element } ]